# C++ Algorithm: Pick n numbers from 2D Matrix based on certain conditions

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a 2D matrix of size [3][x] filled with numbers. I want to pick say x numbers from this matrix based on the condition

1. exactly one number from each column.
2. up to a Max of 'm' numbers from each row (total of all the 3 rows should be x numbers and 3m > x)

I want to find the least possible sum of these selected x numbers.

I was able to pick the numbers based on iterative approach of finding the 'x' small numbers based on above conditions from the matrix. But my answer is not optimal.
E.g.:

```
5 9 . . . . 
6 15 . . . .
7 19 . . . .
```

Lets say 5 is picked up initially(so 6 and 7 cannot be picked now). Later on we try to pick 9 but if m elements of row(0) are over we will have to pick 15. Now our solution will be 5+15 = 20 but we could have used 6+9 = 15 as optimal solution.

I am trying to optimize my solution and looking for better algorithms. Can someone provide me some good idea for optimal solution?

Comment: nope, solving some problem from coding site. minimized the solution to this level and having problem in optimizing.

Comment: What solution are you trying to optimize? Where is your code?

Comment: the matrix is 3 rows by x columns or the other way around? What does [3][x] mean........

Comment: I am finding first 'x' smallest numbers from the 2D array, eliminating small candidates if the column is already having one small number or the max limit of m for the row.

Comment: @Idog, yes its 3 rows by X columns.

Comment: It would be more productive to show your code rather than asking us to understand the problem and find a better solution than the one you aren't showing us.

Comment: You say it is filled with [3][x] numbers.  Then you say "total of all the 3 rows should be x numbers and 3m>x".  Is that the same x?  Is the condition 3m>x saying that 3m>(rows*columns) or 3m>columns?

Comment: And what can m be? Could you give us an example of x, m, and the 2D array. Giving us a link to the problem description would be even better. My current idea is to greedily pick the smallest element in each column, and then while there are more than m chosen elements in a row, somehow choose an element in another row so that the sum doesn't increase much. It would not surprise me if there were dynamic programming involved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem reminds me of this one: http://projecteuler.net/problem=345

The Hungarian algorithm might work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm